# $\langle r\rangle$ maximal $\iff r$ irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a PID, and $r\in R- \{0\}$. Prove that
>   $\langle r\rangle$  maximal $\iff r$ irreducible.

"$\Leftarrow$"Easy.

"$\Rightarrow$"If $J=\langle r \rangle$ then we will prove that $r$ is irreducible. If $r=ab$, we want to prove that $a\in U(R)$ or $b \in U(R)$.

If we take the ideal which is generated by $\langle a\rangle$ then (because $J$ is maximal)$$\langle a\rangle \subseteq\langle r \rangle \iff r\mid a \iff a=kr, k\in R \Longrightarrow r=krb\iff r(1-kb)=0_R \iff kb=1_R$$
so $b\in U(R)$. Same way if we work with $\langle b \rangle$.

Is this proof right?

Comment: I mean, "Easy" is not a proof of anything, so we're taking it on faith that you can indeed prove it.

Comment: If $r=ab$, then $\langle r \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle$, not the opposite. On the other hand, since $\langle r \rangle$ is maximal, then $\langle r \rangle = \langle a \rangle$, therefore...

Comment: Patrick: My friend,i did this proof and i stack in the opposite direction.

Alex: If $r \in \langle r \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle $ then $r \in \langle a \rangle$ and then $r=au, u\in R$. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, if $r \in \langle a \rangle$ then $r = au$ with $u \in R$. But why do you ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is not completely correct.

If I understand correctly you start with "(because $J$ is maximal) $\langle a\rangle \subseteq\langle r \rangle $", but it is not true that if you chose some maximal ideal then every other ideal is contained in it.

Instead argue like this if $r= ab$ then $r \in \langle a \rangle$ and thus $\langle r \rangle \subset \langle a \rangle$. Since $\langle r \rangle$ is maximal it follows that  $\langle r \rangle = \langle a \rangle$ or that $ \langle a \rangle =R$.

Then continue from there.

Comment: You understood right. But why is this wrong? $J$ is maximal. Does it contain  all the other ideals of $R$?

Comment: No. A maximal ideal does not contain all the other ideals. For example in the integers, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal ideal but it does not contain the ideal $9\mathbb{Z}$. Or just note that in general there are several maximal ideals. Not each of them can contain all the other ones.

Comment: Nice example. So by definition the only thing that we can conclude is that:
If for every $I$ ideal of $R$ such that $J \subseteq I$, $J$ is maximal iff $I=J$ or $I=R$?

Comment: An ideal $J$ is maximal if and only if the only ideals that contain it are $J$ and the full ring, yes.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ Note that for principal ideals: $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $(a)\supset (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$ thus

$\qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray} (r)\,\text{ is maximal} 
&\iff&\!\!\ (r)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (a)\\
&\iff&\  r\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ a\\
&\iff&\  r\ \ \text{ is irreducible}\\
\end{eqnarray}$